# shell_exec hangs when no output file is specified

Tags: php, command-line-interface

So, when executing:

`php '_cliScript.php' "535c862d53269d7c027962fccd3f9823" "12f9f2bc98d120848b883a9632e4048d" "444948150528855c6620042134857e6a805e8f92">"/var/www/output.txt" 2>&1 &`

It works like a charm, on the other hand, trying to execute:

`php '_cliScript.php' "535c862d53269d7c027962fccd3f9823" "12f9f2bc98d120848b883a9632e4048d" "444948150528855c6620042134857e6a805e8f92" 2>&1 &`

It just hangs, doesn't even execute the script. Also tried:

`php '_cliScript.php' 535c862d53269d7c027962fccd3f9823 12f9f2bc98d120848b883a9632e4048d 444948150528855c6620042134857e6a805e8f92 2>&1 &`

`php '_cliScript.php' 535c862d53269d7c027962fccd3f9823 12f9f2bc98d120848b883a9632e4048d 444948150528855c6620042134857e6a805e8f92 &`

And they hang too.. :) any suggestions? I'm going mental over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to try to get information back from the script then don't put the `&` on the end, otherwise, if you don't want to output to a file, but don't need any info from the script, then `>/dev/null` instead of a file.

Comment: Don't need the output and tried to redirect output to /dev/null, still hangs :) it's a ***** this one :) ..momentarily i've redirected the output to a file which I delete after the script is finished :).. crappy workaround but gets the job done.. I'll investigate later...